# How to get highlight effect from an invisible button over an imageview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uibutton

I put a button over my imageview. So it is a custom button and have nothing inside of it. It is invisible. I cant change my structure so I have to put that invisible buttons on my imageview.

My question is is it possible also to having highlight effect of the button? Because when I press the button everything is ok. It is working like a charm. But as expected there is no highlight effect. How can I have it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You set the highlighted image for button by below code.

```
 [sender setImage:HIGHLIGHT_IMAGE forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I was asking for the automatic highlight image. in your case I have to define an highlight image right?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting showsTouchWhenHighlighted of UIButton to YES. I hope this was what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up by using a black over image with %50 opacity.